# I want to pass latlng values from one activity to the other in android

Tags: java, android

I made a list with some restaurants in the first activity and what I want is to see in the googlemap the specific location of each restaurant I select every time.How can I  pass these values from the first activity to the maps activity?

Comment: Hint: [`LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng) is `Parcelable`.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is this (from the [Google Map API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents)):-

```
// Create a Uri from an intent string. Use the result to create an Intent.
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.streetview:cbll=46.414382,10.013988");

// Create an Intent from gmmIntentUri. Set the action to ACTION_VIEW
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
// Make the Intent explicit by setting the Google Maps package
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");

// Attempt to start an activity that can handle the Intent
startActivity(mapIntent);
```